# Linear Regression using Payroll Data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am currently analyzing the city payroll dataset for Los Angeles from the year 2016. My goal of the analysis is to use linear regression and plot the diagnostics in order to find potential outliers in the dataset. I then want to use robust regression to demonstrate how it is better suited to deal with outliers than linear regression.

One concern I have is that the dataset has columns such as the job title and department title of the individual alongside their hourly pay, salary, overtime pay, benefits plan, etc. Should I include the job title and/or department title in the regression model if they are character variables? I was thinking of converting them to factor variables, but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach because there's simply so many different job titles and department titles in this data.

When I fit a linear regression model that includes the job title and department title of the individual, I receive the following output.
[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly because it states in the output that 17 coefficients were not defined because of singularities, and to get a Multiple R-squared of 1 is concerning. Any advice?

Comment: Your singularities are likely to be cases where there are departments with only one job title or job titles which only appear in one department.  Your Multiple R-squared of $1$ is due to the very large number of regressors - it is probably so close to $1$ that you cannot see the difference.  If you are looking for curiosities, you might look at the cases with large positive or negative residuals (you will need to examine `mod1$residuals`) and go back to your original data to see other people in the same department or job title, though these may not be outliers.

Comment: "if they are character variables? I was thinking of converting them to factor variables", this is what R does for you. You may consider looking at the job titles and perhaps creating classes that you think are meaningful as it is right now you seem to be having to many levels compared to the amount of observation.